# How would I call the data in this object?

Tags: node.js

I am new to web development and am about half way through a full-stack web development course. How would I go about calling the value of the data stored with the source: "Rotten Tomatoes"?

I have tried `Ratings[1].Value` and it does not seem to work.

```
var movieObject = JSON.parse(body);
console.log('Rotten Tomatoes Rating: ', movieObject.Ratings[1].Value);
```

Body Content:

```
{
"Title": "Avatar",
"Year": "2009",
"Rated": "PG-13",
"Released": "18 Dec 2009",
"Runtime": "162 min",
"Genre": "Action, Adventure, Fantasy",
"Director": "James Cameron",
"Writer": "James Cameron",
"Actors": "Sam Worthington, Zoe Saldana, Sigourney Weaver, Stephen Lang",
"Plot": "A paraplegic marine dispatched to the moon Pandora on a unique mission becomes torn between following his orders and protecting the world he feels is his home.",
"Language": "English, Spanish",
"Country": "UK, USA",
"Awards": "Won 3 Oscars. Another 85 wins & 128 nominations.",
"Poster": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTYwOTEwNjAzMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODc5MTUwMw@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
"Ratings": [
{
"Source": "Internet Movie Database",
"Value": "7.8/10"
},
{
"Source": "Rotten Tomatoes",
"Value": "83%"
},
{
"Source": "Metacritic",
"Value": "83/100"
}
],
"Metascore": "83",
"imdbRating": "7.8",
"imdbVotes": "967,488",
"imdbID": "tt0499549",
"Type": "movie",
"DVD": "22 Apr 2010",
"BoxOffice": "$749,700,000",
"Production": "20th Century Fox",
"Website": "http://www.avatarmovie.com/",
"Response": "True"
}
```

Comment: Did you assign that to a variable?

Comment: @RobertMoskal yes, sorry, I should have included that in the original post.

Comment: Post your actual code then.

Comment: var movieObject = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log('Rotten Tomatoes Rating: ', movieObject.Ratings[1].Value); 

I'll add the body content to the top of the question.

Comment: Welcome to SO, when providing code, try to include the smallest executable example of the problem. This will help us quickly identify the issue. See the guide on [how to ask a good quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Comment: Thanks @LightBender. I will give that a more thorough read.

Comment: Post enough code so we can see what's going on.

Comment: You haven't yet.

Comment: @RobertMoskal Can you see the edits I have made to the original question?

Comment: What does it output in the console? You might be attempting to parse something that has already been converted to an object.

Comment: @LightBender you are correct. That was the issue...thank you so much!

Comment: Is 'body' a string or object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call is correct, so it must be something in the setup. Best guess is that you're calling JSON.parse() on an object that has already been converted to an object.